# Return nested arrays in restful api with dotnet core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, actionresult

I'm writing an api call in dotnet core 3.0 and trying to return several objects.  I can return all the objects as long as the information in them is simple.  But, when I have an array of objects (that also contain arrays) the result for that object is empty.

For example, in the following code, the first three items (a c# object, a list of strings and a string) all return values, but the list of chartdatasets is empty in the result of the call.  It is populated when I step through the code on the server side.

Do I have to do something special to return an array of complex objects?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Chart>> GetCharts()
{
    List<string> axisLabels = new List<string>() {"CLI","MC","MCAL","PAT","PTP","TP"};
    string chartTitle = "Outstanding AR by Fin Group";
    ReturnKey retKey = new ReturnKey() {AuthKey = "asdasdas", Message = "OK"};

    List<ChartDataSet> dataSetList = new List<ChartDataSet>();
    List<double> cData = new List<double>();
    cData.Add(37795.59);
    cData.Add(16839.71);
    cData.Add(144.89);
    cData.Add(90);
    cData.Add(216829.68);
    cData.Add(1764.52);
    List<string> cBg = new List<string>();
    dataSetList.Add(new ChartDataSet("Outstanding AR", cBg, cData));

    return Ok(new {retKey, axisLabels, chartTitle, dataSetList});
}
```

The result in postman looks like this.

```
{
    "retKey": {
        "authKey": "asdasdas",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    "axisLabels": [
        "CLI",
        "MC",
        "MCAL",
        "PAT",
        "PTP",
        "TP"
    ],
    "chartTitle": "Outstanding AR by Fin Group",
    "dataSetList": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! At first sight your return looks odd. Method signature says that you are returning List of Chart, yet in Ok() you create anonymous object. Maybe if you returned Ok(new Chart(...)) it would help?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did try several variations of that.  It turns out it was the definition of the ChartDataSet class.  I posted an example below.  However, I agree with you about the return value.  I will look into changing that to be more flexible and so that it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not post the definition of the ChartDataSet, but it turns out that is where the problem was.  From a discussion with a colleague, we found that the ChartDataSet attributes were not encapsulated.  After adding {get;set} to each attribute I wanted to return in the API, it seems to be working.

```
    [Serializable]
public class ChartDataSet {
    public string label {get;set;}
    public string backgroundColor {get;set;}
    public List<double> data {get;set;}

    public ChartDataSet(string lbl, string bgcolor, List<double> datavalue)
    {
        label = lbl;
        backgroundColor = bgcolor;
        data = datavalue;
    }
}
```